# Why is the constellation Ursa Minor instead of Ursus Minor?

Tags: origin

One of the mythological origins for the constellation Ursa Minor is that it was created by Zeus, who transformed Arcas into the constellation after preventing him from killing his mother, Callisto.

It makes sense that the female Callisto would become a constellation named Ursa Major, but why did Arcas become Ursa Minor and not Ursus Minor? Is it because it got its name from a different myth where the transformed individual was female, and if so, why did the name remain the same?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Greek ἄρκτος is grammatically feminine, both in the meaning “bear” (of either sex) and as the name of the constellation. Latin has ursa for “bear” (of either sex), but also ursus specifically for a male bear. The Latin name – or rather its gender – is calqued on the Greek.

Comment: Learned a new word today: [calque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque).

Comment: I wonder why the Greek word is feminine, since *ἄρκτος* and *ursus* are cognate

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Did you also notice that *calque* is a loanword and *loanword* is a calque? ;-)

Comment: @Asteroides. ursus implies IE  *Hrtƙo- but arktos implies metathesized *Hrƙto-. So they are cognates, but not identical.

Comment: @Asteroides Actually ἄρκτος is given with both genders, depending of the sex of the animal. Considering the declension, it was originally masculine, which is the default gender I guess.

Comment: @Vincent: In Greek, the default and perhaps even only gender of ἄρκτος was feminine according to the discussion here: [Why is ἄρκτος always feminine?](https://www.textkit.com/greek-latin-forum/viewtopic.php?t=68449), *Textkit Greek and Latin Forums*

Comment: @Asteroides May very well be so. Although both the Bailly and Magnien-Lacroix give both genders, Chantraine, who is a very reliable source, states that the examples in the masculine are "dubious". Still, this is the masculine declension, so who knows...